# URL Link from HTML form to PHP page

Tags: php, html, mysql, url, hyperlink

I have read a lot of submissions, I haven't been able to find an answer to my exact question.

I am filling out an HTML form that is sent into mysql database - I am good there.

The results are displayed using php in a html table. I would like the website URL to show as a hyperlink. Everything I do results in an error.

Does anyone know how I can update my code to allow for the website url to show as a hyperlink?

```
[$dbname = "seller";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT website, url, price, name, email FROM listing";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>Website</th><th>URL</th><th>Price</th><th>Contact      Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["website"]. "</td><td>" . $row["url"]. "  </td><td>" . $row["price"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td> " .    $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>]
```

Thanks

Comment: Wrap the url within an anchor. `'<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">Caption</a>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this...

```
echo "<tr><td></td><td><a href='" . $row['url']. "'>" . $row['website']. "</a>  </td><td>" . $row["price"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td> " .    $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
```

You could also just change 'Link to website' to " . $row["website"]. " for it to display the link

Answer (score 1):

If you use an a tag it should work.

`<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">URL</a>`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr><td><a href=\"{$row['url']}>{$row['website']}</a></td>...etc
```

You should also consider closing the tags to get a cleaner code:

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>
    <div>HTML code!</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am new to php, where in my code would I put this? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You have to surround the text you want to be a link with `<a>` , like this: `<a href=\"{$row['url']}>{$row['url']}</a>`. I guess you are new to HTML as well, as this a problem related to HTML and not PHP.

Comment: Yes and no. I have been working with HTML for a while. I am just really getting back into it and trying to improve my skills. So, sometimes I over think answers thinking I am missing something. I closed all my tags. Thanks for replying back.

Answer (score 1):

That will be great if you can show me the error otherwise
Try this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["website"]. "</td><td><a href='".$row["url"]."'>Link</a> </td><td>" . $row["price"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td> " .    $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
 }
```

Comment: It actually made the url an extension of my website. Example: http://google.com/url so it didn't actually make it a url to the clients page.

Comment: Disregard, figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Add an anchor tag `<a href="">` inside the table data tag `<td>` inside your `while` loop.

**Change this line:**

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["website"]."</td><td>".$row["url"]."  </td><td>".$row["price"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td> ".$row["email"]."</td></tr>";
```

**Into this:**

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='".$row["website"]."'>".$row["website"]."</a></td><td>".$row["url"]."  </td><td>".$row["price"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td> ".$row["email"]."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<a>` tag, please see [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

```
'<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['url'] . '</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row["website"]. '</td><td><a href=" ' . $row["url"]. ' ">'; echo $row["name"];    echo'  </a> </td><td>' . $row["price"]. '</td><td>' . '</td><td> ' .    $row["email"]. '</td></tr>';
```

instead of

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["website"]. "</td><td>" . $row["url"]. "  </td><td>" . $row["price"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td> " .    $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
```